# CodeIgniter resize uploaded image doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create a thumbnail of an uploaded image and resize the uploaded image afterwards.
This is my code:

```
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $upload_data = $data['upload_data'];


            //Create image thumbnail
            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config['source_image'] = $upload_data['full_path'];
            $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
            $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
            $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $config['width'] = 150;
            $config['height'] = 150;

            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

            $this->image_lib->resize();

            //Resize original image for space saving purposes
            if ($upload_data['image_width'] > 850 || $upload_data['image_height'] > 850) {

                $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config['source_image'] = $upload_data['full_path'];
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
                $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
                $config['width'] = 850;
                $config['height'] = 850;

                $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
                $this->image_lib->resize();
            }
```

The thumbnail is created just fine, but the resizing of the originial image isn't working. What am I missing here?

EDIT: I have tried adding the line:

```
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

between the two image manipulations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out I need to reinitialize the $config as well, like this:

```
                $this->image_lib->clear();
                $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
                $this->image_lib->resize();
```